# Copying a not so large excel table from another workbook causes issue with defined range

Tags: excel, vba

So I had a prefect sample macro to open a workbook, copy a table to "Feuil1" on another workbook, copy the table on a new sheet and clean up "Feuil1" for another use. Now that I try to scale it up, for some reason, it does copy the defined range but instead of just using range B2:EA201 as coded, Excel forces itself to EA201201 for some stupid reason.

Using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd> brings me to EA201201 which has no formatting or value so i'm at a loss...
Thinking it might have to do with a double letter column, as i've never used that before?
Would you know whats happening?

```
Workbooks.Open fileName:="C:\FilePath\ClasseurX.xlsm"
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))
Dim wsCopy As Worksheet
Dim wsDest As Worksheet
Dim lCopyLastRow As Long
Dim lDestLastRow As Long

    Set wsCopy = Workbooks("ClasseurX.xlsm").Worksheets("Synthèse")
    Set wsDest = Workbooks("ClasseurPrimaire.xlsm").Worksheets("Feuil1")
  lCopyLastRow = wsCopy.Cells(wsCopy.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
  lDestLastRow = wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
  wsCopy.Range("B2:EA201" & lCopyLastRow).Copy _
    wsDest.Range("B" & lDestLastRow)
    

Workbooks("ClasseurX.xlsm").Close SaveChanges:=False

ThisWorkbook.Activate

Dim WSCount As Long
WSCount = Worksheets.Count
'
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Feuil1").Copy _
           After:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(WSCount)
        Sheets("Feuil1 (2)").Name = "NewSheet" & WSCount + 1
        
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Feuil1").Activate
Range("B2:EA201").Clear

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks to @BraX for cleaning up my post !

Comment: `wsCopy.Range("B2:EA201" & lCopyLastRow).Copy` means to copy the range `"B2:EA201" & 201`, if `lCopyLastRow` is 201. So try using `wsCopy.Range("B2:EA" & lCopyLastRow).Copy` ...

Comment: Try changing the line `wsCopy.Range("B2:EA201" & lCopyLastRow).Copy _` to `wsCopy.Range("B2:EA" & lCopyLastRow).Copy _`. Note how I removed the `201`

Comment: That was totally it guys, thank you for your quick answers!